# Discord.js How to add roles when a user joins if the bot is in multiple servers

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

My bot is currently part of multiple server and Im trying to get it to add a role to a user when they join one of the servers, I have done stuff like
`if(bot.guild.id === [SERVER ID])`  and I've tried different forms of the bot.on command to no avail.
the current code is

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', guildMember => {id
    let welcomerole = guildMember.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === 'Nomad');

    guildMember.roles.add(welcomerole);
    guildMember.guild.channels.get([SERVER_ID]).send("Welcome to the server")
})
```

But as per usual it does not work.
I'm not sure if there is a function im missing in the bot.on section of the block, or if the issue is something else. Note I am running Discord.js 11.6, so these functions do or should work with the version. (there is a reason).
Is there is a way to have it so the bot only adds the role to one of the servers that its a part of.

Answer (score -1):

**Just update to Discord.js V13, v11 is many years out of date and new docs solutions won't work with it.**

Comment: I Would update to V13 however alot of the bots systems require V11 and it's way more work than it's worth to upgrade them to be compatible with V13, and from what Im aware I will need to almost recode the basic functions of the bot as most V11 arguments have been changed.